# How do you set up a Flask application with SQLAlchemy for testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, sqlalchemy, flask

It seems common practice in Flask to start like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flaskext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'something'
app.config.from_object(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

And then import and use `app` and `db` everywhere.  But when you create `db` like this, it grabs configuration from the app, and it seems that this configuration can't ever be overridden once it happens.  There are some pages on Flask's website about making application factories, but it's not clear how I would be able to still use `app` and `db` everywhere if I did that.

How do I write a script to test my Flask application with a different database?  How should I structure my application to make this possible?  Do I have to use `module`s ?

Comment: In the meantime, I'm going to use app.config.from_envvar and always specify the configuration file on the commandline when I run my app in different ways.

Comment: that does seem like a solution but if you forget and run tests with the wrong db ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your instinct to use environment variables is correct. However, there is some danger of running unit tests with the wrong db. Also, you may not want to `connect_db` with every request and everywhere you want to use `db`. You can use a config directory and environment variables which you set explicitly. This is the best I've come up with so far.

```
run.py
shell.py

config/__init__.py
config/test.py
config/postgres.py
...

main/__init__.py
main/someapp/__init__.py
main/someapp/models.py

...
main/tests/__init__.py
main/tests/testutils.py
```

so, the config files may be:

```
# config/test.py
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite://"
```

and

```
# config/postgres.py
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://user:pw@localhost/somedb'
```

So, I can explicitly set the db in my base TestCase:

```
import os
from flask.ext.testing import TestCase

os.environ["DIAG_CONFIG_MODULE"] = "config.test"
from main import app, db


class SQLAlchemyTest(TestCase):

    def create_app(self):
        return app

    def setUp(self):
        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
```

Then, the `main/__init__.py`, for me:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, g
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

# by default, let's use a DB we don't care about
# but, we can override if we want
config_obj = os.environ.get("DIAG_CONFIG_MODULE", "config.test")
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config_obj)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = db
    g.app = app

# ...
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get():
    return render_template('home.html')
# ...    
from main.someapp.api import mod as someappmod
app.register_blueprint(someappmod)
```

Then, in the other files, where I know what config I want to run, potentially:

```
# run.py
import os
os.environ["DIAG_CONFIG_MODULE"] = "config.postgres"
from main import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

and

```
# shell.py
import os
os.environ["DIAG_CONFIG_MODULE"] = "config.postgres"

from main import app, db
from main.symdiag.models import *
from main.auth.models import *
print sorted(k for k in locals().keys() if not k.startswith("_"))
import IPython
IPython.embed()
```

Maybe .. best so far :P.

Answer (score 6):

You won't want to make connecting to the db happen at import time.  Go ahead and configure your app at import time because you can always tweak the configuration in your tests before attempting to test or run your app.  In the example below you'll have your db connection behind some functions that use the application config so in a unittest you can actually change the db connection to point to a different file and then go ahead and connect explicitly in your setup.

Say you have a myapp package containing myapp.py which looks like:

```
# myapp/myapp.py
from __future__ import with_statement
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
from contextlib import closing
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, \
     render_template, flash

# configuration
DATABASE = '/tmp/flaskr.db'
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'development key'
USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'default'

# create our little application :)
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.config.from_envvar('MYAPP_SETTINGS', silent=True)

def connect_db():
    """Returns a new connection to the database."""
    return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])


def init_db():
    """Creates the database tables."""
    with closing(connect_db()) as db:
        with app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    """Make sure we are connected to the database each request."""
    g.db = connect_db()


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    """Closes the database again at the end of the request."""
    g.db.close()
    return response

@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    cur = g.db.execute('select title, text from entries order by id desc')
    entries = [dict(title=row[0], text=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

Your test file myapp/test_myapp.py will look like this:

```
import os
import myapp
import unittest
import tempfile

class MyappTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.db_fd, myapp.app.config['DATABASE'] = tempfile.mkstemp()
        self.app = myapp.app.test_client()
        myapp.init_db()

    def tearDown(self):
        os.close(self.db_fd)
        os.unlink(myapp.app.config['DATABASE'])

    def test_empty_db(self):
        rv = self.app.get('/')
        assert 'No entries here so far' in rv.data
```

Of course if you'd like to use SQLAlchemy you'll have to update the connect_db and init_db functions appropriately but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Mike: In that code snippet, it will make connection each time when a request come. Don't you think it would slower your application for a heavy overhead of connection call?

Comment: Yeah, it is not ideal.  For sqlite3, I doubt you'll notice, but for  a connection to a networked database (mysql, postgresql, mssql, mongo, cassandra, etc)  you would want a connection pool to reduce the overhead.

Comment: :) cause I found that problem when I use mysql

Answer (score 4):

First, instead of instantiating Flask app directly in your script, you use an [application factory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appfactories/). It means you create a function that takes your config file as parameter, and return the instantiated app object. Then, you create the global SQLAlchemy object without parameter, and you configure it when creating the app, [as explained here](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/contexts.html).

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(configfile):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_pyfile(config, silent=True)
    db.init_app(app)

    # create routes, etc.

    return app
```

To run the app, you simply do something like:

```
app = create_app('config.py')
app.run()
```

To run unittests, you can do something like:

```
class Test(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # init test database, etc.
        app = create_app('test_config.py')
        self.app = app.test_client()
    def tearDown(self):
        # delete test database, etc.
```

In my case, I'm using SQLAlchemy directly with scoped_session instead of Flask-SQLAlchemy.
I did the same, but with [Lazy SQLAlchemy setup](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/22/).