# In Flask: When using wtforms, SQLAlchemy, getting "OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table:" when the table exists

Tags: sqlite, python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

I've got a pretty basic flask application in the works and I am having a problem with saving data to a sqlite database and table that most definitely exist and does take form submissions if I use a direct `execute()` method like so:

```
def get_db():
    if not hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db = connect_db()
    return g.sqlite_db
...

gdb = get_db()
gdb.execute("insert into term (term_txt) values (?)", (form.term_txt.data,))
gdb.commit()
```

The model for which is:

```
class Term(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    term_txt = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, term_txt):
        self.term_txt = term_txt

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Term %r>' % self.term_txt
```

The form is:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
<form action="{{ url_for('addTerm') }}" method="POST">
    {{ form.term_txt }}
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <p><input type="submit" label="Add Term"></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

But if I try to use the Flask suggested way of doing it as in this route, i get the following error `OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: term [SQL: u'INSERT INTO term (term_txt) VALUES (?)'] [parameters: (u'my test term',)]`:

```
@app.route('/add_term', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def addTerm():
    form = AddTermForm(csrf_enabled=True)

    if request.method == "POST":
        newTerm = Term(term_txt=form.term_txt.data)
        db.session.add(newTerm)
        db.session.commit()
        #gdb = get_db()
        #gdb.execute("insert into term (term_txt) values (?)", (form.term_txt.data,))
        #gdb.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('terms'))
    else:
        return render_template('new_term.html', form=form)
```

`db` comes from:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_envvar('FLASKAPP_SETTINGS', silent=True)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

As mentioned, the database exists and I can save from the form to the database if I use the above sql command in the code, but I don't feel like that's the best approach.

Also I don't know if the sql command should be in the error or not, maybe something is wrong there. Otherwise, I can't figure out why this isn't working as it appears across a number of docs that this is the way to do it.

Comment: Does this one work: `gdb.execute("insert into term values (?)", form.term_txt.data)`?

Comment: Yes it does, but I was hoping to use more of SQLAlchemy's built in stuff and not have to do all the sql by hand

Comment: Have you run `db.create_all()`?

Comment: @IanAuld you know this made me realize that i'd set up the database another way and that the connection between the app and the db was wrong for using SQLAlchemy to insert to or update the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it looks like the database for SQLAlchemy was configured incorrectly. The db had been created without SQLAlchemy. Following this made it work: [How do you set up a Flask application with SQLAlchemy for testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025720/how-do-you-set-up-a-flask-application-with-sqlalchemy-for-testing)